# Include Detailed Contents entry in short TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

With the `memoir` documentclass, I have both a Short Contents (chapters and sections only) and a Detailed Contents (also subsections, which happen to be unnumbered).

Is it possible to include the entry "Detailed Contents" in the Short Contents table *without* including the entry "Contents" in the Detailed Contents, and vice versa?

Source:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

{\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Short Contents}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
  \tableofcontents
}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Detailed Contents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents 

\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter} 

\section{Section 1}

\subsection*{First subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{First subsection}

\subsection*{Second subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Second subsection}

\section{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

First page of output:

[image: Short and detailed TOCs]

Of course:

- using the starred form `\tableofcontents*` for only the Detailed Contents produces the entry "Short Contents" in both TOCS (but "Detailed Contents" in neither);
- using the starred form `\tableofcontents*` for only the Short Contents produces the entry "Detailed Contents" in both TOCs (but "Short Contents" in neither); and
- using the starred form for both produces no entry for either TOC in either of the TOCs.

Comment: `memoir` emulates `tocloft`, which in turn uses `\newlistof` instead the traditional `\tableofcontents` definition. The `\contentsname` addition to the ToC is hardcoded -- once it is there, it is written to the `.toc` file. You rather need two different tocs!

Comment: Do you need `hyperref` here?

Comment: Yes, I *am* using `hyperref`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution, by using a `\if@shorttoc` switch and writting dummy `\contentsline` to the ToC, which are evaluated at the time of loading the `.toc` file in `\@input{\jobname.toc}` (hidden in `\@starttoc` usually)

If `\@shorttoctrue` is set, `\longcontentsstuff` will show the contentsline meant for the detailed contents, correspondingly it is `\relax`ed for `\@shorttocfalse, accordingly the opposite is done for` \shortcontentsstuff`.

Simplification is done with `\shorttableofcontents` and `\longtableofcontents`, both having an optional argument that is used as value for the `tocdepth` counter. (I know, there are `memoir` equivalents of this tocdepth as well)

In order to provide `hyperref` support some 'heavy' tricks has to be used.

- Perhaps I can look after a `memoir` based solution later on.
- Of course, my redefinition of `\tableofcontents` is not compatible with `memoir`'s version, especially with the `\tableofcontents*` way.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}



\makeatletter

% Just in case we're not loading hyperref
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
}{
  \providecommand{\@currentHref}{}
  \providecommand{\hyperlink}[2]{#2}
  \providecommand{\getrefnumber}[1]{}
  \providecommand{\phantomsection}{}
}


\AtBeginDocument{%
\newcommand{\shortcontentsstuff}{%
  \contentsline{chapter}{\hyperlink{\getrefnumber{toc::shorttoc::anchor}}{\shortcontentsname}}{\pageref{toc::shorttoc}}{\getrefnumber{toc::shorttoc::anchor}}
}

\newcommand{\longcontentsstuff}{%
  \contentsline{chapter}{\hyperlink{\getrefnumber{toc::longtoc::anchor}}{\longcontentsname}}{\pageref{toc::longtoc}}{\getrefnumber{toc::longtoc::anchor}}
}
}

\newif\if@shorttoc

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \else
  \@restonecolfalse
  \fi
  \chapter*{\contentsname
   \@mkboth{%
     \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
 % Addition
 \if@shorttoc
 \protected@edef\@currentlabel{shorttoc}% Rather unimportant
 \edef\@currentlabelname{\shortcontentsname}% For \nameref
 \label{toc::shorttoc}% 
 % Now let us fix the hyperanchor for the short toc
 \edef\@currentlabelname{}%
 \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\@currentHref}\label{toc::shorttoc::anchor}
 \else
 \protected@edef\@currentlabel{longtoc}% Rather unimportant
 \edef\@currentlabelname{\longcontentsname}
 \label{toc::longtoc}%
 % Now let us fix the hyperanchor for the long toc
 \edef\@currentlabelname{}%
 \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\@currentHref}\label{toc::longtoc::anchor} 
 \fi
 % End of additions
 \@starttoc{toc}%
 \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}

\newcommand{\longcontentsname}{Detailed Contents}
\newcommand{\shortcontentsname}{Short Contents}

\newcommand{\shorttableofcontents}[1][1]{%
  \begingroup
  \@shorttoctrue
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{#1}
  \let\shortcontentsstuff\relax
  \phantomsection
  \write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}{\protect\longcontentsstuff}}
  \let\contentsname\shortcontentsname% Disabling the \shortcontentsstuff in toc
  \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
  \@shorttocfalse% Disable the short toc
}

\newcommand{\longtableofcontents}[1][3]{%
  \begingroup
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{#1}
  \phantomsection
  \let\longcontentsstuff\relax% Disabling the \longcontentsstuff in toc
  \write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}{\protect\shortcontentsstuff}}
  \let\contentsname\longcontentsname
  \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother




\begin{document}


\frontmatter


\shorttableofcontents

\longtableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter} 

\section{Section 1}

\subsection*{First subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{First subsection}

\subsection*{Second subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Second subsection}


\section{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

**Short ToC**
[image]

**Detailed ToC**
[image]

The hyperlinks are not shown here...

Comment: Interesting solution! Alas, at this point I'm committed to the `memoir` document class.

Comment: @murray: It is a `memoir` solution -- don't blame me for hardcoded stuff in `memoir`

Comment: Thanks for the solution!  I realize this required modifying low-level `memoir` package code. Always nice if a solution is available that does not require such mods, since then it's likely to be robust when package changes.

Comment: @murray: Packages & classes change once in a while but most times they gain other functionality by using new macros and features rather than break the old stuff. I am pretty confident that my solution is not really low-level ;-)

Comment: Certainly hope old stuff doesn't break with new versions! "Low-level" is evidently in eye of beholder. When I say it, I mean code that changes something in a package (notably when `@` appears!) rather than by using options or additional packages. But no disparagement of the fix intended.

Comment: This method to obtain two TOCs has one defect: it totally ignores whatever `pagestyle` has been set; the only thing that appears in headers after the title page of Short Contents or of Detailed Contents is the page number (and no head rule if one has been set in the `pagestyle`).