# memoir: Exclude entry of other TOC from each of two TOCs

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, etoc

I'm using the `etoc` package with the `memoir` document class to get two tables of contents (TOCs): a Short Contents listing only chapters and sections, and a Detailed Contents also including subsections.

**Aim:** I want neither TOC to be self-referential, but each to refer to the other. That is, I want the Short Contents to include an entry for the Detailed Contents but not for itself; and the Detailed Contents to include an entry for the Short Contents but not for itself.

**Constraint:** The memoir `pagestyle` and `chapterstyle` in effect need to be preserved.

(Compare [memoir: headers for short and detailed tables of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512742/memoir-headers-for-short-and-detailed-tables-of-contents).)

The method shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346433/13492, unfortunately, does *not* preserve the `pagestyle` for pages after chapter page in the Short Contents and the Long Contents. It does, however, produce the wanted entries of each of the two TOCs in, and only in, the other; and it makes the links on each of those entries point to the top of the corresponding TOC page.

**Attempt:** The following MWE *almost* accomplishes this:

- the Detailed Contents does have an entry for Short Contents but not for itself; however,
- the Short Contents does just the opposite of what I want -- it has an entry for itself but not for the Detailed Contents.

Note that the Detailed Contents is produced with `\tableofcontents*`, the *starred* version whereas the Short Contents is produced with `\tableofcontents`, the *un*starred version.

*Caution:* If I use the starred version for both tables, then neither table has entries for either itself or the other one.

**Question:** How can I accomplish my aim?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\pagestyle{plain}
\chapterstyle{default}

\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% TOC STUFF
\usepackage{etoc}

\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\etocsettocdepth{1}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Short Contents}
\tableofcontents  % <--- unstarred
\clearpage

\etocsettocdepth{2}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Detailed Contents}
\tableofcontents* % <--- starred
\clearpage

\mainmatter

\newcommand\Sample{
  \chapter{Chap}This is a chapter.
  \section{Sec}This is a section.
  \subsection{Subsec}This is a subsection.
}
\Sample\Sample

\end{document}
```

[image: Detailed Contents OK]

[image: Short Contents WRONG]

**A partial solution not using `etoc`**

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512752/13492.

**However, this method not using `etoc`* **does *not* work if `biblatex` is also loaded**. See:  [memoir + biblatex + 2 TOCs error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513429/memoir-biblatex-2-tocs-error.tocs-error) .

Comment: I apologise but I haven't come up with a solution to your problem.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the answer I provided to the other question? Now, I even figured out how to get the cross ref to jump above the toc header.

Comment: @daleif: Just saw your amended answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512742/memoir-headers-for-short-and-detailed-tables-of-contents, and that does everything I requested. Thank you1

Comment: @PeterWilson it is doable with memoir alone, see the added link to the OPs question

Comment: @PeterWilson: but the added link in the OP's question gives a method that fails if `biblatex` is also loaded! See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513429/memoir-biblatex-2-tocs-error

Comment: @murray I have already said that I haven't come up to a solution to your problem. Why are you complaining to me me about someone else solution? GOM

Comment: @PeterWilson: Sorry, I seem to have interchanged references. It looks like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512752/13492 completely solves the problem for me; I'm just checking it now against my actual (non-MWE) book source.